# Coffeescript disregard some of multiple return values of a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function that returns a pair of values. At some points in my code, I only need the second value. In Scala, I could do something like this:

```
[_, secondValue] = functionThatReturnsAPair()
```

which would discard the first value. Is there such a mechanism in coffeescript, or do I have to declare a variable which is ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but this will do it:

```
[..., a] = functionThatReturnsAPair()
```

Comment: This will do something subtly different if said function doesn't return two items.

Comment: @GeorgeSimms sure, `a` will always be assigned the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have a function which returns a pair of values. That means that your function actually returns a two element array. So you can say:

```
a = functionThatReturnsAPair()[1];
```

The downside of this is that it sort of hides the `[1]` off at the right side.